# Socks version 22 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)

Tags: configuration, security, socks, torsocks, ssl

Hello everyone. i have a simple question i am using a tor client to connect programmatically to tor via Socks4a. Everything run smoothly but when i tried to add ssl-tls to connect to localhost  i got the message below.

```
Socks version 22 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
```

The reason that i want to implement ssl-tls is to prevent someone doing MITM  between my pc and the proxy which has been setted localhost. Is this possible via socks proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not trying to speak SOCKS, the SOCKS port only speaks the SOCKS protocol.

Decimal 22 is hexadecimal 0x16, which is the initial byte of a TLS connection. Tor's SOCKS port does not speak TLS. You cannot arbitrarily add TLS onto the SOCKS connection.

No one can MITM between you and a localhost proxy without being an administrator or having privileges on your local computer. If they a *are* local administrator then adding TLS will not stop them performing MITM or worse.